# list<T> - sql like statements for retrieving data

Tags: c#

I have the following table

```
public class QTable
{
    public string QID { get; set; }
    public string QNO { get; set; }
    public string Q1 { get; set; }
    public string Q2 { get; set; }
    public string opt1 { get; set; }
    public string opt2 { get; set; }
    public string opt3 { get; set; }
    public string opt4 { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    public string KnowledgeArea { get; set; }
    public string Hints { get; set; }
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public string ToughLevel { get; set; }
    public string DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string DeleteMe { get; set; }

}

 QID is my primary key.
```

I have the

```
 List<Qtable> qtableList = <list of all values of qtable from a query>
```

I need to find a particular QID and take other fields for manipulation.
Is there a SQL statement like structure to manipulate these things for a list?

Comment: Google `LINQ` and you'll see.

Comment: Use qtableList.FirstOfDefault(a => a.QID.Equals(otherId));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use to get the item you want

```
Qtable item = qtableList.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.QID == id);
```

Just be aware that if the QID dont exists on the list and you try to access one of its properties, an 'Object reference is not an instance of an object exception' will be thrown, since you are trying to access a null object.

To prevent that, check if the return is differente of null prior to access and modify the properties you want.

Answer (score 3):

In C# the best sql ike approach is just simply use linq, it's maded to handle this kind of request.

The basic syntax is:

```
var query = from qt in qtableList
            where qt.QID == "1"
            select qt;
```

This is basically returning the first pk element of your data.

Insert, update and other basic sql operations working as well.

More about on this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations